# Elasticsearch terms aggregate duplicates

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field using a ngram analyzer and trying to use a terms aggregate on the field to return unique documents by the field.  The returned keys in the aggregates don't match the documents fields being returned and I'm getting duplicate fields.

```
"analysis" : {
   "filter" : {
     "autocomplete_filter" : {
        "type" : "edge_ngram",
         "min_gram" : "1",
         "max_gram" : "20"
      }
    },
    "analyzer" : {
      "autocomplete" : {
        "type" : "custom",
        "filter" : [ "lowercase", "autocomplete_filter" ],
        "tokenizer" : "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}

"name" : {
  "type" : "string",
  "analyzer" : "autocomplete",
  "fields" : {
    "raw" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "index" : "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}

{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query":"bra",
      "fields":["name"],
      "use_dis_max":true
     }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_name": {
      "terms": { "field":"name.raw" }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting back the following names and keys.

```
Braingeyser, Brainstorm, Braingeyser, Brainstorm, Brainstorm, Brainstorm, Bramblecrush, Brainwash, Brainwash, Braingeyser

{"key":"Bog Wraith","doc_count":18}
{"key":"Birds of Paradise","doc_count":15}
{"key":"Circle of Protection: Black","doc_count":15}
{"key":"Lightning Bolt","doc_count":15}
{"key":"Grizzly Bears","doc_count":14}
{"key":"Black Knight","doc_count":13}
{"key":"Bad Moon","doc_count":12}
{"key":"Boomerang","doc_count":12}
{"key":"Wall of Bone","doc_count":12}
{"key":"Balance","doc_count":11}
```

How can I get elasticsearch to only return unique fields from the aggregate?

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates being returned in your aggregate you can try:

```
"aggs": {
  "group_by_name": {
    "terms": { "field":"name.raw" },
    "aggs": {
      "remove_dups": {
        "top_hits": {
          "size": 1,
          "_source": false
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```